# Request throws NULL while calling Laravel image upload API from React Native App

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, native, cloudinary

I am using Laravel API for image uploading to Cloudinary. The API is working fine on postman but throws a NULL request error while accessing the endpoint in the React Native app. Could someone please let me know if there’s any way to troubleshoot and resolve it?
Laravel API for uploading to Cloudinary

```
public function uploadImageIntervention(Request $request)
{
   $image = $request->file('img');
   $name = $request->file('img')->getClientOriginalName();
   $image_name = $request->file('img')->getRealPath();;
   Cloudder::upload($image_name, null);
   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image_name);
   $image_url= Cloudder::show(Cloudder::getPublicId(), ["width" => $width, "height"=>$height]);
   //save to uploads directory
   $image->move(public_path("uploads"), $name);
   return Response::json([
    'is_uploaded' => (bool)User::where('id', $request->input('id'))->update(['image' => $name , 'image_path' => $image_url])
  ]);   
}

//Method to pick image 
 const pickImage = async () => {
 setUploadFailed(false);
 let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
 mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
 allowsEditing: true,
 aspect: [4, 3], 
 quality: 1,
 });

 if (!result.cancelled) {
 setImage(result);
 }
};
 //method to handle submit button 

const handleSubmit = async () => {
setLoading(true);

let photo = new FormData();

photo.append("image", {
  name: `photo.jpg`,
  type: image.type,
  uri:
    Platform.OS === "android"
      ? image.uri
      : image.uri.replace("file://", ""),
});

let result = await photo.uploadPhoto(user.user.id, photo, user.token);
console.log("@@@ result", result.data);
if (!result.ok) return setLoading(false);
setUploadFailed(true);

setLoading(false);
};
//api client 

import apiClient from "./client";
const uploadPhoto = (id, image, token) =>
apiClient.post(
"/api/user/image",
{
  id,
  img: image,
},
{
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json",
  },
 }
 );
  export default {
  uploadPhoto,
 };
```

This is the response when I send request to Laravel api.

```
result Object {
 "id": 27,
 "img": Object {
 "_parts": Array [
  Array [
    "img",
    Object {
      "name": "image.jpg",
      "type": "image",
      "uri": 
    "file:///Users/fawadmac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8E677CA0-646A-442A-A7B1-8BAADF70E480/data/Containers/Data/Application/40261E62-4CCA-449F-A9D2-10A9D5046203/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540fawad55%252Fgenie/ImagePicker/9F29927C-1E7A-4DC1-8A89-3E89B220D233.jpg",
    },
  ],
],
},
```

}

Comment: Hey Muzafar; I see you contacted our support team about this directly and I replied a few minutes ago - it seems like this may be because your image field is called `image` in the form data, and you're looking for `img` on the server side - can you check that please?

Comment: @Igy I edit the post and share the response above when request sent to Laravel.

Comment: Where is the error happening?, is `Cloudder::upload($image_name, null)` working, or the path sent to Cloudder can't be opened? do you receive an exception or stacktrace, or it's just that the upload() function returns null?